# Need help! How to export mysql database from a system os drive, that is not running

Tags: 16.04, mysql, disk

I had a web server running on an hdd, ubuntu 16.04, on an LVM. I did mount the LVM in my Ubuntu workstation, to pull off the website an realised that i didn't export the mysql database yet, now it won't boot no more....

My question is, how can i export the mysql database from that system os drive? I can mount the drive no problem.

Any help is welcome, also help for booting my old hdd again is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can install mysql on your machine where you connected your hdd that has a database. Then change location of your database to your hdd location i.e. old database or copy the old database to the newly installed one. Finally dump it using the dump command. [This tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files) may help you.